# For Each loop in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with three parameters:
    Parameter 1 - has 200 data 
    Parameter 2 - has 6 data
    Parameter 3 - 150 data

I want to dump all possible combinations of the result into a table. Any ideas please?
I want to do something like the following 
 For each Parameter 1
    For each parameter 2
       For each parameter 3

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please add data in the tables you are calling the types of things you do with each parameter and expected results.

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: The answer you seek lies here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: To obtain all possible results without modifying your procedure, you must call procedure with all possible parameters

Comment: "all possible combinations" depends on the data type. if all the parameters are of `bit` type, then you have 7 possible combinations (ignoring null values, otherwise it's 27). If one of the parameters is tinyint and the other two are bits, you have over 1000 possibilities (again, ignoring possible null values). If all are strings, you have such a huge number of possibilities I don't even want to start thinking about it.

Comment: SQL is all about thinking in *sets* rather than thinking about *loops*. It's trivial to join 3 sets (with 200 rows, 6 rows and 150 rows) together to form a single result set, but what you do with it is unclear (maybe filter down to interesting combinations?)

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever here. Write your `200 data`, `6 data` and `150 data` to their own temp tables in the proc then `SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3;` and you will get the Cartesian product (all possible 180k combinations)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the parameters are table valued parmeters, and by "data" you mean rows - to get all possible combinations you use a cross join, just like with regular tables:

```
-- It's better practice to specify the columns but I don't know what your columns are...
SELECT * 
FROM @TVP1
CROSS JOIN @TVP2
CROSS JOIN @TVP3
```

The cross join will return every possible combination between the rows of both tables - here is another example to help you visualize this:

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    Col int
);

INSERT INTO @T (Col) VALUES (0), (1);


SELECT  t1.Col As C1, 
        t2.Col As C2,
        t3.Col As C3
FROM @T t1
CROSS JOIN @T t2
CROSS JOIN @T t3
ORDER BY C1, C2, C3


C1  C2  C3
0   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   1   0
1   1   1
```